# Kotlin - Random.nextInt Range

Tags: kotlin

Aim of code: Shopping system,function which shows a matched product name from the warehouse

1. what is the no. range of Random.nextInt() if no no. is assigned inside ()? 
   in fun fillWarehouse, if i do not set no. inside "StockUnit(Random.nextInt(),Random.nextInt())", when i call println("Number of items: ${p.availableItems}") in main, No. -890373473 / 1775292982 etc. were generated.
2. if i set 100 inside like "StockUnit(Random.nextInt(100),Random.nextInt(100))", No. 263 / 199 etc. were generated. why is it not within 0-100? may i know how to change my code, so that "Number of items" is within 100?
3. any links or topics should i work for, to write better code?

i cannot find the answers from https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/
Sincere thanks!

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val warehouse = Warehouse()
...
println("Show info")
showInfo(warehouse)
}

    fun showInfo(warehouse: Warehouse) {
    println("Get Info")
    val input = readLine() ?: "-"
    val p = warehouse.getProductByName(input)
    if (p != null) {
        println("Product: $p")
        println("Number of items: ${p.availableItems}")
        println("Profit: ${p.profitPerItem}")
    }
}
```

---

```
    class Warehouse {
    private val products = mutableListOf<Product>()
    ...
    fun getProductByName (productName: String): Product? {
        for (prod in products)
            if (prod.productName == productName) return prod
    return null
    }

  fun fillWarehouse (productName: String,
                   basePrice: Double,
                   productDescription: String,
                   chargeOnTop: Double = 50.0,
                   intialStockUnits: Int = 3) {

    val newProduct = Product(productName, basePrice, basePrice * (1 + chargeOnTop / 100), productDescription)
    //add quantity, daysBeforeExpiration
    for (i in 1 .. intialStockUnits){
        val unit = StockUnit(Random.nextInt(),Random.nextInt() )
            newProduct.addStock(unit)
    }
```

---

```
    open class Product(
   val productName: String,
    var basePrice: Double,
    open val salesPrice: Double,
    val description: String) {

   ...
    var stockUnits = mutableListOf<StockUnit>()
   ...
    // availableItems = Total of stockUnits
    var availableItems: Int = 0
        get() = stockUnits.sumBy { it.quantity }
    }
```

---

```
    class StockUnit(var quantity:Int, var daysBeforeExpiration:Int){
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is documentation built-in for all the standard library functions. Alt+Middle Click the function you're curious about.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-int.html